# Rails active record model as a mixin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Anyone know how to define a active record model using `include` mixin vs class inheritance *(`class Car < ActiveRecord::Base`)*.

I cant find the syntax anywhere, but I know it was introduced in Rails 3.1/3.2

Comment: your question is not clear. can you explain properly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to something like this?

```
class Car
  include ActiveModel::Model
end
```

although this will not give you persistence. What are you trying to do exactly?